# Get the item in a listbox that was unchecked using Click Event C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I created a Winforms application in C# VS2008.  The ListBox is a ComponentOne list box.  It has a CheckedListBox. (Each item has a checkbox which the user can select.)  I created a Click Event so when the user selects an item by clicking the checkbox, it runs a query to a database to retrieve data.  That works fine.  I need to identify when the user unchecks a selection.

When I uncheck a selection the lstbxBatchNumbers.SelectedText retrieves the last SELECTED item.
How can I get the item that was unchecked?

The click event has parameters (Object sender, EventArgs e) but they are for the ListBox not the specific row that was clicked.

Is there any way to do this?  Below is the click method:

```
private void c1lstbxBatchNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tiSelectedBatchNumberCounter = 0;

    int tiBatchNumberColumn = 0;
    string tstrDelimitBatchNumbers = "', '";
    string tstrBatchNumberList = string.Empty;
    DataTable tdtBatchDetails = new DataTable();

    if (dsCasePick.Tables["SelectedBatchNumbers"].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dsCasePick.Clear();
    }

    //HERE I NEED TO FIND OUT IF THE ITEM CLICKED WAS UNCHECKED?


    //Check if there is a Batch Number in the Cancel Pick Table that is not selected
    //If there is, give the user the option to add to list and keep the rows or remove rows from Cancel Pick Table
    string tstrBatchNumberInCancelTable = string.Empty;


    string tstrUncheckedBatchNumber = e.ToString();
    foreach (DataRow cancelRow in dtCancelPick.Rows)
    {
        string tstrCancelBatchNumber = cancelRow["BatchNumber"].ToString();
        if (c1lstbxBatchNumbers.SelectedText.Equals(tstrCancelBatchNumber))
        {
            tstrBatchNumberInCancelTable = tstrCancelBatchNumber;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tstrBatchNumberInCancelTable))
    {
        string tstrError = "The Batch Number, " + tstrBatchNumberInCancelTable + ", has been unselected and has values in the Cancel Pick Grid to be cancelled.\n";
        tstrError += "Do you want to continue and have these picks removed from the Cancel Pick Grid?";
        DialogResult Answer = MessageBox.Show(tstrError, "Cancel Picks Not Selected", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        if (Answer == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //Remove batch number from the Cancel Data Table
            string tstrFilter = "BatchNumber = '" + tstrBatchNumberInCancelTable + "'";
            DataRow[] rowsToDelete = dtCancelPick.Select(tstrFilter);
            foreach (DataRow row in rowsToDelete)
            {
                //Remove the button from the grid       
                foreach (HostedControl hosted in alRemoveCasePickBtns)
                {
                    Button ctl = hosted._ctl as Button;
                    if (ctl.Tag.ToString().Equals(row["WorkReference"].ToString()))
                    {
                        ctl.Dispose();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                dtCancelPick.Rows.Remove(row);
           }
           dtCancelPick.AcceptChanges();
           c1flxgrdCancelPick.Refresh();
       }
       else
       {
           //Check the Batch Number in the List
           int tiIndex = c1lstbxBatchNumbers.FindStringExact(tstrBatchNumberInCancelTable);
           c1lstbxBatchNumbers.SetSelected(tiIndex, true);
       }
    }

    //Does more stuff ...
}
```

The initialization of the ListBox Control:

```
 // 
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.AddItemSeparator = ';';
        this.SetCaption(this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers, "Batch Numbers");
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.CaptionHeight = 25;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.ColumnCaptionHeight = 25;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.ColumnFooterHeight = 25;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.ColumnHeaders = false;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.DataMode = C1.Win.C1List.DataModeEnum.AddItem;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.DeadAreaBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.DefColWidth = 90;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.Images.Add(((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("c1lstbxBatchNumbers.Images"))));
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.ItemHeight = 25;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(363, 12);
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.MatchEntryTimeout = ((long)(2000));
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.Name = "c1lstbxBatchNumbers";
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.RowDivider.Style = C1.Win.C1List.LineStyleEnum.None;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.RowSubDividerColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.SelectionMode = C1.Win.C1List.SelectionModeEnum.CheckBox;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 164);
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.TabIndex = 13;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.TabStop = false;
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.Text = "Batch Numbers";
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers_Click);
        this.c1lstbxBatchNumbers.PropBag = resources.GetString("c1lstbxBatchNumbers.PropBag");
```

Comment: Just a thought - may or may not work Have you tried listbox1.SelectedItems.Contains?

Comment: The .Selected properties only work if the checkbox is checked.  I need to identify the item that triggered the event when it is Unchecked.  I would have thought that somehow, maybe using the parameters, I can identify the checkbox item that triggered the event.  Then determine if it was 'CHECKED' or 'UNCHECKED'.  I have not found the property.

Comment: How are you declaring the CheckBoxes for the ListBox in xaml?  You can add an event handler for the CheckBox.Unchecked event, then in the code behind do the logic based on what checkbox causes it to fire

Comment: No.  THis is a WinForm application.  I am using a ComponentOne ListBox.  One of the properties of this ListBox is to set the 'SelectionMode' to 'Checkbox'.  I added the initialization code of the ListBox above.

Comment: Refer to the OnItemChecked event.  The ItemCheckEventArgs passed to the event will contain the check state.

Comment: I only see this event associated with a ListView, not a ListBox.  If I have to go in that direction, I will keep that in mind.  Is there any event I can use for a ListBox?